# Binding DataGrid's FontWeight property to value converter

Tags: c#, silverlight, xaml

I'm trying to make cell bold or normal if item new/old inside DataGrid but stumbled upon erro..

Looks like my issue described here: [Why can I not bind the Visiblity of a DataGridTemplateColumn in Silverlight 4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3433396/why-can-i-not-bind-the-visiblity-of-a-datagridtemplatecolumn-in-silverlight-4)

I'm getting following error:

> Object of type 'System.Windows.Data.Binding' cannot be converted to
>   type 'System.Windows.FontWeight'.

And my XAML looks like so:

```
<sdk:DataGridTextColumn Header="Subject" Binding="{Binding Subject}" CanUserReorder="True" CanUserResize="True" CanUserSort="True" Width="Auto" FontWeight="{Binding IsNew, Converter={StaticResource BoolToFontWeightConverter}}" />
```

My question is there any workaround to get this working? I'm not even using template column, it's plain text column..

```
public class BoolToFontWeightConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            return ((bool)value) ? FontWeights.Bold : FontWeights.Normal;
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            return (FontWeight)value == FontWeights.Bold;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Is return type of your converter is equal to FontWeight type?

Comment: Converter code never get's hit - I added code

Comment: Unfortunately, [`FontWeight`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagridtextcolumn.fontweight(v=VS.95).aspx) is not a dependency property

Comment: Any workarounds to make it work? Maybe create my own Grid column?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The FontWeight property of the DataGridTextColumn is not a dependency property and thus will not support bindings.  A workaround would be to use a DataGridTemplateColumn with a TextBox as the DataTemplate and set the appropriate bindings there, something like:

```
<sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Subject" 
                    CanUserReorder="True"
                    CanUserResize="True"
                    CanUserSort="True"
                    Width="Auto">
    <sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Subject}" FontWeight="{Binding IsNew, Converter={StaticResource BoolToFontWeightConverter}}"/>
      </DataTemplate>
    </sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

Comment: Is it possible to achieve the same, but thru DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle? Using template is not always desirable.